# remove a child div when they are multiple w.r.to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs which are created dynamically like this:

```html
<div id="starredDiv">
  <div class="list-group" id="starredList">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
      <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
      <a class="a-file">message.txt</a>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-primary" style="float: right;"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
      <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
      <a class="a-file">testcase.txt</a>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-primary" style="float: right;"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="recentDiv">
  <div class="list-group" id="recentList">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
      <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
      <a class="a-file">message.txt</a>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-primary" style="float: right;"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
      <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
      <a class="a-file">testcase.txt</a>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
      <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-primary" style="float: right;"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want delete the list-group-item w.r.to `<a>` present in starredList when user clicks on the glyphicon-star button of recentList. For this I have written some thing like this:

```
var file = $(this).closest('.list-group-item').children('.a-file').text();

  if($(#starredList).children('.list-group-item').children('.a-file').text() == file){
    $(#starredList).children('.list-group-item').remove();
  }
```

This works when starredList is present with one list-group-item but not on multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.list-group-item` are multiple so you need to loop through on it,

```
$('#starredList').children('.list-group-item').each(function(){
  if($(this).children('.a-file').text() == file){
     $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
var file = $(this).closest('.list-group-item').children('.a-file').text();

$('.list-group-item').not($(this).closest('.list-group-item')).each(function(){
   if($(this).find('.a-file:contains('+file+')').length > 0){
       $(this).remove();
   }
});
```